# Javascript ES6 recursion function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion, task

I wonder how does this recursion function return numbers in this empty array(`return n < 1 ? []`) without pushing from `[n, ...countdown(n - 1)]`, or how does it push? maybe I don't understand that es6 syntax

`function countdown(n){ return n < 1 ? [] : [n, ...countdown(n - 1)] }`

`console.log(countdown(5))`  log: `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

Comment: You should indeed just read what the spread operator does. PS: The function is not a good way to generate that desired result. Try e.g. `countdown(20000)` vs `Array.from({ length: 20000 }, (_, i) => 20000 - i)`, but i guess its purpose is to showcase ES6 features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call stack steps that produce the result:

```
1. n = 5 => [5, ...countdown(4)]
2. n = 4 => [5, 4, ...countdown(3)]]
3. n = 3 => [5, 4, 3, ...countdown(2)]]
4. n = 2 => [5, 4, 3, 2, ...countdown(1)]
5. n = 1 => [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, ...countdown(0)]
6. n = 0 => [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, ...[]]
```

So the `...` is spreading syntax notation that works like `concat` for two arrays.

Another schema could be like:

```
1. n = 5 => [5, ...countdown(4)]
2. n = 4 => [5, ...[4, ...countdown(3)]]
3. n = 3 => [5, ...[4, ...[3, ...countdown(2)]]]
4. n = 2 => [5, ...[4, ...[3, ..[2, ...countdown(1)]]]]
5. n = 1 => [5, ...[4, ...[3, ...[2, ...[1, ...countdown(0)]]]]]
6. n = 0 => [5, ...[4, ...[3, ...[2, ...[1, ...[]]]]]]
```

Think about that like function call stack from left to right:

```
x1( x2( x3() ) ) => ...( ...( ...(n) ) )
```

Comment: Do you mean this?

`1. n = 5 => [5, ...countdown(4)]
2. n = 4 => [5, [4, ...countdown(3)]]
3. n = 3 => [5, [4, [3, ...countdown(2)]]]
4. n = 2 => [5, [4, [3, [2, ...countdown(1)]]]]
5. n = 1 => [5, [4, [3, [2, [1, ...countdown(0)]]]]]
6. n = 0 => [5, [4, [3, [2, [1, ...[]]]]]]`

Comment: The next call will return `[n, ...countdown(n-1)]` so the result of each call is an `array` and the return value will be concatinated with last one by  spreading syntax nottion (`...`)

Answer (score 3):

The `...`-prefix syntax in this specific context (called the "[spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)") puts the elements of the `...`-prefixed array directly into the surrounding array.

```
[ 5, ...[4, 3, 2, 1] ]
```

is the same as

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

That's just what is happening here. The return values of `countdown` (from base case up to `countdown(5)`) look like:

```
[]
[1, ...[]]             => [1]
[2, ...[1]]            => [2, 1]
[3, ...[2, 1]]         => [3, 2, 1]
[4, ...[3, 2, 1]]      => [4, 3, 2, 1]
[5, ...[4, 3, 2, 1]]   => [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```